# CocoaPods can't install Google/SignIn 4.1.2 and Firebase 4.6.0

Tags: firebase, cocoapods, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-signin

Everytime that I try to update one of them, the other one receive a downgrade.

Google/SignIn just is accepting Firebase 3.*
Firebase just is accepting Google/SignIn 3.*

But I need the 4.* version of then.

What should I do? I think I will need to update a part of my code.

This is what happens when I try to force the version of the two pods:

```
Update all pods
Updating local specs repositories
Analyzing dependencies
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "Google/SignIn":
  In Podfile:
    Google/SignIn (~> 4.1.2)

None of your spec sources contain a spec satisfying the dependency: `Google/SignIn (~> 4.1.2)`.

You have either:
 * mistyped the name or version.
 * not added the source repo that hosts the Podspec to your Podfile.

Note: as of CocoaPods 1.0, `pod repo update` does not happen on `pod install` by default.
```

My podfile:

```
...
target ... do
use_frameworks!

pod 'AFNetworking'
pod 'GoogleMaps'
pod 'Google/SignIn', '~> 4.1.2'
pod 'GooglePlaces'
pod 'HCSStarRatingView'
pod 'SDWebImage'
pod 'Socket.IO-Client-Swift'
pod 'CircleProgressBar'
pod 'UICountingLabel'
pod 'MKDropdownMenu'
pod 'InLocoEngage-iOS-SDK', '~> 4.0.1'
pod 'InLocoMedia-iOS-SDK/Location', '~> 4.0.1'
pod 'Firebase/Core', '~> 4.6.0'
pod 'Firebase/Messaging'

end
```

I already tried `pod repo update`, `pod update`, `pod install` and `pod deintegrate`

CocoaPods version `1.5.3`

`GoogleSignIn` is different of `Google/SignIn`, if I change it, I will need to update the code that is what I realy don't want (I didn't this code, I don't know what is happening).

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The `Google` pod (and its SignIn subspec) have been deprecated and haven't been updated for awhile. To use `GoogleSignIn` with other recent Google pods, it needs to be specified directly in the Podfile:

`pod 'GoogleSignIn'`

Comment: I know! This app is very old, some parts of code need to be updated. Anyway I just removed Google SignIn, I discovered that it didn't work.

Comment: @AngelPereira, I also faceing the same issue how you resolve it, please let me know